# How can I get the contents of a div correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a div with some HTML-Code:

```
<div id="MyDiv" contentEditable="true">
<p>This is the first P</p>
    <p id="MyPId">
        <ol>
            <li>Text 1</li>
            <li>Text 2</li>
        </ol>
   </p>
</div>
```

During run-time I need the HTML-Code. But just as it is in DIV, correct!
Something like below give me a wrong result [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sbpmyLh9/):

```
var MyHTML = $('#MyDiv').html();
alert( MyHTML );
```

The resulte of it will be as follows:

```
<p>This is the first P</p>
    <p id="MyPId">
        </p><ol>
            <li>Text 1</li>
            <li>Text 2</li>
        </ol>
   <p></p>
```

Look closely, that's not my previous code in DIV and also "p" is missing.
Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This is not related to jQuery, it's not a bug,  `p` elements can't have `ol` or `ul` child. `p` element can only have [*phrasing content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content). Browser itself closes the `p` element when it comes to the `ol` element.

`innerHTML` is the string representation of the *parsed* HTML content of the elements. Form elements have `defaultValue` (`textarea`, `input[type=text]`, ...), `defaultChecked` (`input[type=checkbox]`) and other similar properties for storing some of the form related values, but this is not the case for other elements, i.e. there is no `defaultInnerHTML` or similar properties.

One possible solution is getting the element's content via AJAX, so you will have the original html instead of the parsed one. Note that after parsing (by setting `innerHTML`) you will have the same result.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/a/resource',
}).done(function(originalHTMLReturnedByTheRequest) {
     // 
});
```

Another *hackish* method is using a `script` tag with an *unknown* `type` attribute or a hidden `input`. By using a `type` attribute that is unknown to the browser, the interpreting of the `script` tag is prevented:

```
<script id="originalHTML" type='whatever'>
   <p>This is the first P</p>
   <p id="MyPId">
      <ol>
          <li>Text 1</li>
          <li>Text 2</li>
      </ol>
   </p>
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var defaultContent = $('#originalHTML').html();
```

Comment: Without jquery and for UL is the same.

Comment: @user3815508 take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbpmyLh9/1/) to understand what this is all about.

Comment: But is it possible to prevent the code correcting. Because by correcting the HTML code will be wrong ... which in my Projkt can not be more printed. (I have now understood, but it is rather intended for others e.g. users). In addition, I can't comprehend, -2 votes, What is this?

Comment: @user3815508 `innerHTML` is the string representation of the _parsed_ HTML content of the elements, form elements have `defaultValue`, `defaultChecked` and other similar properties, but this is not the case for other elements. One possible solution is getting the element's content via AJAX, so you will have the original html instead of the parsed one. Note that after parsing (by setting `innerHTML`) you will have the same result. Another hackish method is using a `script` tag with an unknown `type` attribute.

Comment: In addition I think that's a good question, because it shows DOM has a bug. It must not deliver a wrong HTML-Code as a result of because after "p" follows "ol".

Comment: @user3815508 That's not a bug. That is intended. When you have invalid HTML it's up to the browser how it parses it. Different browsers, different results.

Comment: @Vohuman Thanks for the reply. Could you maybe me a small example, how can I handeln with AJAX in order to get the element content via AJAX as it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, very nice. But if I use "unscript", then I won't be more able to use my DIV-Id, like a normal HTML element. E.g. the Id of DIV-Element will no longer valid or usable as usual.
In case of "$.ajax" unfortunately instead of URL it is an Id "myDiv", I don't know if it would be used still. I think it is needed maybe something as follows:   $.get(...,"MyDivId" ...). Because the HTML-Code is in a contentEditable-DIV not in url (file).